# How can I upload xlsx file to BigQuery?

Tags: excel, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, xlsx

I am wondering how I can upload an .xlsx file to BigQuery. I get data in this format once a week and would like to upload it manually. So far I have been copying this data to Google Sheet and from there with a connector to BigQuery, however Google Sheet is starting to hang up more and more with this amount of data and I am looking for another solution. I know that the easiest way would be to convert the data to csv, but the problem is the data itself contains a lot of commas, semicolons and other characters so every time I tried to convert it to csv the data was wrong. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to upload xlsx or convert it so that the data can be easily uploaded to BigQuery.

Comment: I have the same problem. You could write a python script to extract the data from the xlsx file and upload it to BigQuery. But in my case, the user do not have python on their computer. Having a bucket which triggers such a python script as soon an user uploads such a file, could be the solution, but I did not finished it yet. For small excel files, I have in productive cases Excel functions, which build a BigQuery struct for each row. This only works for data less than 1 MB. Another solution for you could be to remove `,` and `;` in the Excel file, then export it to csv, upload this to gcs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your excel file with a different change your delimiter such as pipe ¦ or tilde ~

The value for the separator that is used within Excel when you save a csv is stored with

- Region (not region settings)
- Additional setting
  [image: Region control panel]
- List Separator

Change to something that your data will not be using, apply inside Customise Format and apply again inside the Region dialog.  Next time you save a csv this list separator will be used.

In BigQuery, you can then define your custom separator on table load under additional setting as shown below

[image: BigQuery custom separator]